# IGBT vs MOSFET inverter (which is better)?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, inverter, gate-driving, igbt

I am developing a full-bridge inverter with a working frequency of 100 kHz. I am confused about whether to use IGBTs or MOSFETs. The inverter is to output a 40V square wave signal. I have previously used MOSFETs IRF 540n with IR2110 gate driver but faced different issues and could not get the right results.
Will IGBTs work better for the required inverter configuration? Also, can anybody recommend some optocoupler based IGBT gate driver which can be controlled with microcontroller PWM signal?

Comment: At 40 V MOSFETs are going to have substantially less losses for a given price point unless you are in kA of current, if then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IGBTs have a saturation voltage, FETs have an on resistance.  The die area of a FET increases substantially with voltage rating, where IGBTs at high voltages can have smaller dies.  (Lower cost).

IGBTs are also a minority carrier device, so turning them off takes time compared to a FET.  So higher switching losses and lower frequency operation is typical vs. FETs.

For low voltages FETs usually win, because the RDSon times the current is less than the saturation voltage.

For higher voltages, GAN FETs, SiC FETs, or IGBTs are usually the winner.

For 40V and 100kHz I would certainly consider conventional silicon FETs, but you can do the comparison between cost and losses for the various options.

Comment: @Usama Toor eGAN FETs solve some of the silicon FET issues due to lower capacitance and no intrinsic body diode.

Comment: Ok I will check that.